# jQuery returns wrong data

Tags: jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and strange things are happening with my code. jQuery returns always the same number, even when I press different images. Where is the problem?

HTML code

```js
$(".image-upload").on("change", function() {
  console.log($(this).children("label").find("img").attr("data-id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input">
<img src="<?= base_url("upload.png"); ?>" width="100" height="100" data-id="1"/>
</label>
    <input name="photos[]" id="file-input" type="file" data-ids="1" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="image-upload">
    <label for="file-input">
    <img src="<?= base_url("upload.png"); ?>" width="100" height="100" data-id="2"/>
</label>
    <input name="photos[]" id="file-input" type="file" data-ids="2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

When on change is triggered, console shows 1, no matter on which img a pressed. Why?

Comment: So 'on' 'change' is ONLY for form elements, you would have to monitor the 'src' of the <img/> tag after the action that starts the 'change'

Comment: unable to recreate the issue,as i am getting the proper data , without changing the code just added to the welcome_message.php of codeIgniter as to handle base_url() [php]
please have a look at the screenshot here which is giving correct result
https://i.imgur.com/XeoKD1N.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like writing it like this:

```
$(this).children("label").children("img").attr("data-id")
```

will output the correct data-id. Notice the usage of "children" instead of "find".

Also, it's usually better to provide some type of online example so that it's easier to run and test the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/947f2hhf/

Answer (score -1):

```
  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="image-upload">
                        <label for="file-input">
                            <img src="<?= base_url("upload.png"); ?>" width="100" height="100" data-id="1"/>
                        </label>
                        <input name="photos[]" id="file-input" type="file" data-ids="1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div class="image-upload">
                        <label for="file-input">
                            <img src="<?= base_url("upload.png"); ?>" width="100" height="100" data-id="2"/>
                        </label>
                        <input name="photos[]" id="file-input2" type="file" data-ids="2" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

> html tag id must to be unique. Must be changed Second file-input tag ‘id’.

Comment: Please be more specific with your questions.